# How to get rid default xml namespace if I one to serialize an object in wcf using datacontact

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

Here is my interface

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]      
interface IParam     {     }
```

Here is my class

```
public class Parameter : IParam
{

    private string categoryName;

    [DataMember]
    public string CategoryName
    {
        get { return categoryName; }
        set { categoryName = value; }
    }


}
```

My operation contact is

```
[OperationContract]
string GetSegmentsByCategoryName(Parameter Params);
```

Here is my main:

```
Parameter abc = new Parameter ();
abc.CategoryName = "xxx";

str = client.Channel.GetSegmentsByCategoryName(abc);
```

when I check at wireshark i got this xml

```
<Params xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<CategoryName>
xxx
</CategoryName>
</Params>
```

i one to get rid of xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance when I pass the object through wcf httpbinding.

Comment: are you trying to do this because the consumer of the message is parsing the xml too strict and discarding the message because of the namespace ? If that is so, it might not be a good idea to remove the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't the default/element namespace, though - it is simply an unused alias to a namespace that *might* be used. It isn't actually breaking anything. I would strongly advise to simply leave it alone.

If you really, ***really*** wanted to do this - perhaps write a [message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx).